# Have case and break on same indentation level with ES-lint

Tags: eslint

I'm trying to configure `es-lint` in a way where my `case` and `break` statements are on the same indentation level for my `switch` statements.

With `"indent": [2, "tab", { "SwitchCase": 1, "VariableDeclarator": 1 }]` it expects the `break` on 1 indentation further then the `case`.

With `"indent": [2, "tab", { "SwitchCase": 0, "VariableDeclarator": 1 }]` it for some reason expects both the `case` and `break` on the same level as the `switch` which is not what I want.

Is it possible to create an indent rule as in the following?

```
switch (type) {
    case INSERT_PERSON:
        /* do stuff */
    break;

    // ...
}
```